# Replace null cells with 0 or blank

Tags: excel, null

How can I replace null cells from all my worksheets in a workbook to 0 or blank (" ") in VBA?

Let's say I have some columns with text and columns with numbers:

```
Text Integer
AA   3
BB   null
null 9
DD   6
EE   null
```

From the sample above, I want to replace my null cells with 0 if my adjacent column cells are numeric and blank (" ") for all adjacent column cells that are in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I fully understand your question, but could it be that you are looking for this simple replace command?

```
Cells.Replace What:="Null", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Let me know, or provide some more detail in your question.

Comment: By the way, when you want to "conditionally" replace, what do you mean by adjacent? Is that left or right. Also do you mean that 9 null null is going to be replaced by 9 " " 0, since the last null had text (null) to the left?

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your reply.. adjacent top or bottom.. Since on integer column, all are numbers, I want to replace null values with 0s and for Text column, I want to replace just a blank space.

Comment: Now that the example has been updated, I think that I would just do a replace from "null" to " " in column A:A and a replace from "null" to  "0" in column B:B. Is my thinking correct?